# assembly language count all 'a' in character input

Tags: assembly, tasm

my code supposed to count all character 'a' in every user input i use cmp if equal then my program jump to 'incre:' that increment the value of bl.the output is always  this>¶< .i don't know where the problem is

```
title sample.prog
cstack segment para stack 'stack'
dw 200h
cstack ends

cdata segment para 'data'
msg1 db 'ENTER 9 CHARACTER: $',10,13
msg2 db 10,13,'NUMBER OF a: $'
cdata ends

ccode segment para 'code'
assume cs:ccode,ds:cdata,ss:cstack
main:
 mov ax,cdata
 mov ds,ax

 mov ah,09h
 lea dx,msg1
 int 21h

 mov cl,0
 mov bl,30h

input:
 mov ah,01
 int 21h
 inc cl

 cmp al,61h
 je incre


 cmp cl,9
 je incre
 jmp input

incre:
 inc bl

 cmp cl,9
 jne input

 mov ah,09h
 lea dx,msg2
 int 21h

 mov ah,02h
 mov dh,bl
 int 21h

 mov ah, 4ch
 int 21h

ccode ends
end main
```

ENTER 9 CHARACTERS:aaadfasfg
NUMBER OF a: ¶

ENTER 9 CHARACTERS:fffffffff
NUMBER OF a: ¶

ENTER 9 CHARACTERS:dasdawdaf
NUMBER OF a: ¶

Comment: `mov dh, bl` RONG - you want `dl`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your code:

```
 mov ah,02h
 mov dh,bl    <-- HERE
 int 21h
```

The character should be placed in `dl`, not in `dh`.

Another problem is that you're incrementing `bl` one time too many:

```
 cmp al,61h
 je incre

 cmp cl,9
 je incre  <-- Wrong. al didn't equal 'a', so we shouldn't jump to incre.
 jmp input
```

That should be changed to something like:

```
 cmp al,61h
 je incre

 cmp cl,9
 je done  ; We're done. Jump past the end of the loop without incrementing bl
 jmp input

incre:
 inc bl

 cmp cl,9
 jne input
done:
```

Or even simpler:

```
cmp al,61h
jne no_inc
inc bl
no_inc:
cmp cl,9
jne input
```